# Redirect to HTTPS when user is logged in with URL Rewrite 2

Tags: asp.net, iis, https, url-rewriting, forms-authentication

Does anyone know how to use URL Rewrite 2 in IIS to redirect to an https version of the requested URL if the user is authenticated (via Forms Authentication).

Basically I just want to ensure that users login over https and their entire session remains in https whilst they're logged in.

I know I can set the requireSSL attribute for the Forms Authentication cookie, so I'm doing that as well, but would like the redirect from http to https as well.

I think we can put code in Global.asax instead to achieve what I want, but it would be tidier (and possibly better for performance) if we can define this in Web.config using URL Rewrite 2.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using ASP.NET MVC then this action filter can help, credit must go to the original author.

```
//http://weblogs.asp.net/dwahlin/archive/2009/08/25/requiring-ssl-for-asp-net-mvc-controllers.aspx
public class RequiresSsl : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        var req = filterContext.HttpContext.Request;
        var res = filterContext.HttpContext.Response;

        //Check if we're secure or not and if we're on the local box
        if (!req.IsSecureConnection && !req.IsLocal)
        {
            if (req.Url != null)
            {
                var builder = new UriBuilder(req.Url) { Scheme = Uri.UriSchemeHttps, Port = 443, Host = req.Url.Host.StartsWith("www.", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) ? req.Url.Host : "www." + req.Url.Host };
                res.Redirect(builder.Uri.ToString());
            }
        }
        base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Kane, sorry I should have said we're using ASP.NET web forms not MVC.